# How To Automate AWS Directory Service Integration with License Manager for User-Based Subscriptions

Tags: active-directory, aws-cloudformation, ms-office, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, aws-directory-services

I've successfully automated my AWS infrastructure setup using CloudFormation, covering VPCs, AWS Directory Service, and the Directory Service control instance.

However, I'm having trouble automating the configuration of License Manager to associate Microsoft Office subscriptions to users within my directory service and network setup.

I can do it manually based on the AWS docs:
[image: Manual Configuration]

However, I'm looking for an automated solution.

Has anyone dealt with a similar situation or knows how to automate sharing AWS Directory Service with License Manager for setting up user-based subscriptions, whether by somehow calling the API directory with Python or maybe a custom resource or something?

Or is this is possible natively with Cloudformation?

Thanks?